# JavaScript - Clearing multiple intervals in HTML5 Canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am creating a Canvas game of 'Snake'. Using your arrow keys, you can move the snake around.

What I'm working on is clearing an interval when a different arrow key is pressed. I am trying to make use of both `setInterval` and `clearInterval`. Here is one of the four such functions I have.

https://jsfiddle.net/2q1svfod/2/

```
function moveUp() {
    if (direction != "up") {
        incrementScore();
    }
    direction = "up";
    if (direction == "up") {
        var goUp = setInterval(function() {
            ctx.lineTo(headX, headY - 10);
            ctx.stroke();
            headY -= 10;
        }, 1000);
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(goUp);
    }
}
```

The objective is to avoid crashing into the walls, which will result in losing the game, and your score will be reset. I'd like to prevent players from repeatedly tapping on a key to get extra points, so I only increase their score once per direction.

As long as the direction stays the same, I want the interval to keep running. That's why I declared the `goUp` interval inside this conditional.

If the direction has changed, I clear that interval. However, two intervals are now going on at the same time instead of 1.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Just use a single animation loop that runs continuously and then set/clear flags to allow/disallow game actions. BTW, consider using `requestAnimationFrame` as your animation loop (many reasons to do so).

Comment: I agree with @markE, with that said, you have to var goUp outside your function to make clearInterval work. also, to avoid multiple instances you can clearInterval before setting a new setInterval just to be safe. basically, if (goUp != null) clearInterval(goUp);

Comment: I didn't know you could use animation with canvas. Anyways, is it a better practice than intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one implementation (out of many) you might consider.

```
var currentInput = {
    left: false,
    up: false,
    right: false,
    down: false
};

function getKey(keyCode) {
    if (keyCode === 37) {
        return 'left';
    } else if (keyCode === 38) {
        return 'up';
    } else if (keyCode === 39) {
        return 'right';
    } else if (keyCode === 40) {
        return 'down';
    }
}

function onKeyDown(event) {
    var key = getKey(event.keyCode);
    currentInput[key] = true;
}

function onKeyUp(event) {
    var key = getKey(event.keyCode);
    currentInput[key] = false;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, false)
document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp, false)

function update() {
    requestAnimationFrame(update);

    if (currentInput.left) {
        // move snake left
    } else if (currentInput.right) {
        // etc.
    }
}

// Kick off the event loop
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution, but I'm not too thrilled I had to resort to using global variables.

It looks something like this

```
function moveUp() {
    if (direction != "up") {
        incrementScore();
    }
    direction = "up";
    clearInterval(goRight);
    upArrow();

}

function upArrow() {
    if (direction == "up") {
        goUp = setInterval(function() {
            ctx.lineTo(headX, headY - 10);
            ctx.stroke();
            headY -= 10;
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

It works and I'm able to change directions. But I don't like using globals.

Here's the updated fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/2q1svfod/6/